# How to add dynamic textbox in java script

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create text box using JavaScript. I coded as below:

```
<script>
function _(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

function popuptxt() {
    var i = _("no_room").value;
    for(a = 1; a <= i; a++) {
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "Room number for " + a + "<br><input type='text' name='mytext'+ i><br>"
    }
}
<script>
```

HTML file:

```
<input type="text" style="width:200px;" id="no_room" onChange="popuptxt()" required>
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

It displays number of textbox when I type a number, but I need to clear them when I type another number.

Comment: How is it a PHP question ?

Comment: so you enter `10` and get 10 textboxes, and then you enter `4` and need to remove the extra 6 that were created previously?

Comment: No it is javascript one

Comment: So why adding a PHP tag ?

Comment: yes I need like this

Comment: You got several errors in your js: 1.: `my_div` is never defined. 2.: `name='mytext'+ i>` would need to be `name='mytext'"+ i +">`

Comment: Ok I will change it,,,sorry

Answer (score 1):

Just reset the content of you block each time :

```
<script>
function _(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

function popuptxt() {
    my_div.innerHTML = "";
    var i = _("no_room").value;
    for(a = 1; a <= i; a++) {
        my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "Room number for " + a + "<br><input type='text' name='mytext'+ i><br>"
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `my_div.innerHTML = "";` before the for loop in popuptxt(). That way it will be cleared each time its called.

Comment: Hi hooda,,,now i need to submit and enter database this textbox values,,,,how should i do it,,,please help me